# Setting my Div to 1024 x 768 px

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a Div with a background image whose width x height is 1024px x 768px . And it has to fit whole browser window .

Using the below css i could achieve a image occupying full screen but the image gets cropped

```
 html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
        }

    #wrapper {
            background-image : url(home.jpg);
            background-position: top center !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            min-height: 100%; 
            width : 100%;
            height : 100%;
        }

        #container {
            height: 100%;
        }
```

I tried @media option to set the width and height using below css but now i get full image with scroll bar and a white space means the image is not occupying full screen.

```
 html, body {
    height: 768px;
   width: 1024px;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
        }

#wrapper {
            background-image : url(home.jpg);
            background-position: top center !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center;
            height: 768px;
            width: 1024px;

        }

        #container {
            height: 100%;
        }

@media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px){
    // your code
}
```

Can someone guide me how can i accomplish it and it has to work in all the browser :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that your *screen* resolution doesn't have to match your *browser* resolution. You have browser chroma (title bar, address, bookmarks etc), you have OS UI (task bar/launcher) etc.

So you can get that exact size **only** if you're using a larger screen (e.g. 1600x900), but otherwise you'll run into issues.

But whatever, let's say you really, really, **really** want to match that size.

You have to ditch `background-size: cover;` in favor of `background-size: contain;`, so you'll have the image resized to the container (see the specs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)) and place the image to `top left` (instead of `top center`).

As a side note, I suggest you to use `vh` and `vw` units:

```
#wrapper { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; max-width: 1024px; max-height: 768px; }
```

This way you won't lock your users on a certain resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You Want to add below codes to get div which size is 1024 * 720 just do as follows.

```
@media body
{

    width:1024px;
    height:720px;

}
```